# Quel est la valeur exprimée dans cette phrase?

Tags: conditionnel

> Souhaiter un anniversaire, c'est entretenir la nostalgie du temps qui passe, c'est compter les années passées alors qu'il ***faudrait*** se tourner vers le futur.

Le conditionnel dans cette phrase exprime-t-il :

- un regret
- un souhait
- ou bien une hypothèse ?

Comment: Pourquoi ne serait-ce qu'un de ces trois choix ?

Comment: Cette question était dans un examen.

Answer (score 2):

Il n'exprime aucune de ces possibilités  ; ce qui est exprimé c'est seulement le fait que l'action considérée dans la principale est accomplie au détriment d'une autre action (se tourner vers le futur), à laquelle on reconnait implicitement un degré supérieur de nécessité (falloir).

Cela est justifié par la locution « alors que », qui dans les mots du TLFi, « marque la discordance, l'incompatibilité des deux faits que l'on rapproche ».

La phrase suivante est construite de la même façon, seulement les termes changent; on voit que l'on ne peut rien déceler de tel dans cette phrase, ni regret, ni souhait, ni hypothèse ; c'est confirmé par la remarque finale ; on pourrait peut être supposer que le locuteur ressent de la consternation ou quelque chose de similaire, mais cela ne dépend pas du mode conditionnel.

- Ils nettoient les fonds de marmite avec un chiffon alors qu'il faudrait un grattoir ; en plus ils vous disent que vous n'y connaissez rien !

Il n'y a pas la moindre expression de regret dans cette phrase, et ce que l'on pourrait y trouver c'est de la désapprobation ; donc, que ce soit le regret, l'hypothèse ou le souhait, il faut que d'autres indicateurs que le mode du verbe les mettent en valeur. Le conditionnel est utilisé ici pour atténuer l'énonciation de la vérité d'un état de chose  et insister sur le fait que cet état de chose n'est pas reconnu. Si on utilise le présent de l'indicatif on ne considère plus l'action comme étant connectée à la situation mais généralement et il n'y a pas d'atténuation. Le conditionnel a été longtemps, à tort, compris comme un mode ; cette erreur a été éliminée par les linguistes modernes, lesquels ne voient plus dans les temps du conditionnel que des temps du présent, cela selon la [BDL](http://bdl.oqlf.gouv.qc.ca/bdl/gabarit_bdl.asp?id=4136).

- Ils nettoient les fonds de marmite avec un chiffon alors qu'il faut un grattoir ; en plus ils vous disent que vous n'y connaissez rien !

Dans ce cas on énonce un principe généralement admis, sans insister sur le fait que dans le contexte considéré ce principe n'est pas appliqué.

En récapitulation, cet emploi du conditionnel sert à atténuer l'énonciation d'une vérité générale, tout en la rendant particulière au contexte donné, alors que le présent sert à énoncer une vérité générale sans en atténuer l'énonciation. Il n'y a pas une bien grande différence entre les deux modes dans le présent contexte (une modalité dont certains se passent facilement).

Answer (score 2):

S'il y avait une et une seule réponse à donner, je dirais que cela exprime un **souhait**.

Supposons que les trois solutions soient envisageables :

- un **regret** : l'auteur constate que l'anniversaire se tourne vers le passé et il regrette qu'il ne soit pas plutôt tourné vers le futur ; dans ce cas le regret exprime la [définition B. 2.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/regret) :

> Contrariété causée par une réalité qui s'oppose à la réalisation d'une
>   attente, d'un désir, d'un souhait, d'un projet

- un **souhait** : l'auteur émet une préférence de se tourner vers le futur, il espère que la vision future l'emportera sur le passé ; dans ce cas le souhait exprime la [définition A.](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/souhait) :

> Désir, exprimé ou non par quelqu'un, d'obtenir quelque chose pour lui
>   ou un autre, de voir un événement se produire.

- une **hypothèse** : l'auteur, tel un philosophe ou un scientifique, suggère d'explorer le futur pour voir ce qu'il a à offrir, dans ce cas l’hypothèse exprime la [définition A. 1. a)](http://www.cnrtl.fr/definition/hypoth%C3%A8se) :

> Proposition reçue, indépendamment de sa valeur de vérité, et à partir
>   de laquelle on déduit un ensemble donné de propositions.

Si c'est une hypothèse, il faudrait qu'elle permette de déduire d'autres propositions, ce qui n'est pas le cas dans cet extrait isolé, il est donc assez peu probable que ce soit le sens que l'auteur ait voulu donner.

Le regret est bel est bien présent dans le texte, mais ce n'est pas exprimé au travers du conditionnel. Si l'auteur avait choisi un autre temps que le conditionnel, le regret serait toujours présent. Par exemple :

> Souhaiter un anniversaire, c'est entretenir la nostalgie du temps qui
>   passe, c'est compter les années passées alors qu'il **fallait** se
>   tourner vers le futur.

On ne peut donc pas dire que le conditionnel exprime directement le regret.

Pour le souhait, le temps colle parfaitement. Si on change le temps (comme l'exemple ci-dessus), cela n'exprime plus du tout un souhait.

D'où ma préférence pour le souhait.

Answer (score 0):

> Souhaiter un anniversaire, c'est entretenir la nostalgie du temps qui passe, c'est compter les années passées alors qu'il ***faudrait*** se tourner vers le futur.

D'après moi le conditionnel sert ici à exprimer un souhait, je dirais même une **volonté**, dont voici la définition d'après le [Larousse](https://www.larousse.fr/dictionnaires/francais/volont%C3%A9/82476):

> Disposition de caractère qui porte à prendre des décisions avec fermeté et à les conduire à leur terme sans faiblesse, en surmontant tous les obstacles : Avoir une volonté de fer. Une entreprise qui exige de la volonté.

L'idée étant donc que fêter un anniversaire revient à regarder et à célébrer le *passé*, alors qu'il serait plus intéressant de se concentrer sur le *futur*.

Answer (score 0):

... alors qu'il serait mieux de ...

... alors que pour être plus (?adjectif?) il faudrait ...

C'est donc un conseil, comme *tu aurais dû te tourner*.

La condition du conditionnel n’est pas explicite - si vous voulez faire mieux, ou si vous êtes d’accord. Peut-être que vous pouvez le lire comme un vœu (je voudrais du café, s'il vous plaît) mais je pense qu’ici c’est plus fort, c’est un conseil.

Ou, comme le dit LPH, en fait la condition est de ne pas se tourner vers le passé.